Induction motors torque measurement
I am to calculate the running efficiency of a 3-Ph squirrel cage induction motor. I have the rated data for the motor. I have the load speed of the motor but I need output torque to calculate the efficiency. How do I measure it?

With a torque meter. Have you tried to do a search on the subject? Isn't efficiency stated in the datasheet?

Have you tried this calculator? https://www.calculatoratoz.com/en/torque-of-squirrel-cage-induction-motor-calculator/Calc-37518

The usual method is to use a "brake". eg the motor is used to drive a drum that is loaded at a known radius with a floating brake band for which the rotational torque can be measured. Traditionally this was done using an arm with a spring balance or similar but nowadays a load cell is more often used. || A good search term is "dynamometer."

Dynamometer

Even better: Prony brake

It can be this simple - and This works quite well.

As is known, the mechanical power P of a rotating body is given by the product of the torque τ by the angular velocity ω i.e. P=τω. From which τ=P/ω.

I dont think i can move the setup of the motor to couple the torque meter. But I read strain gauges also work. Has anyone used them before??

To calculate the output torque of a 3-phase squirrel cage induction motor, you'll need to measure the electrical parameters and use them along with the motor's rated data.
You should have the rated power \$\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{rated}\$, rated voltage \$\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{rated}\$, rated current \$\displaystyle\text{I}_\text{rated}\$ and rated speed \$\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{rated}\$ of the motor. These values are usually provided by the manufacturer and are found in the motor's datasheet. You've mentioned you have the load speed of the motor \$\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{load}\$, which is good. Make sure to measure it accurately. Slip \$\displaystyle\text{S}\$ is the difference between synchronous speed and rotor speed, expressed as a percentage. It can be calculated using the formula:
$$\text{S}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{s}-\text{N}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{s}}\cdot100\space\text{%}\tag1$$
Where \$\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{load}\$ is the measured load speed, \$\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{s}\$  is the synchronous speed of the motor (in RPM), which can be calculated:
$$\text{N}_\text{s}=\frac{\displaystyle120\text{f}_\text{line}}{\text{#}_\text{poles}}\tag2$$
Where \$\displaystyle\text{f}_\text{line}\$ is the line frequency and \$\displaystyle\text{#}_\text{poles}\$ is the number of poles.
Now, calculate the rotor speed \$\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{rotor}\$:
$$\text{N}_\text{rotor}=\text{N}_\text{s}\left(1-\text{S}\right)\tag3$$
The output torque \$\displaystyle\text{T}_\text{out}\$ can be calculated using the formula:
$$\text{T}_\text{out}=\frac{\displaystyle1000\text{P}_\text{rated}}{2\pi\text{N}_\text{rotor}}\tag4$$
Where \$\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{rated}\$ is the rated power of the motor (in kW) and \$\displaystyle\text{N}_\text{rotor}\$ is the rotor speed (in RPM).
Once you have the output torque, you can calculate the motor's efficiency \$\displaystyle\eta\$ using the formula:
$$\eta=\frac{\displaystyle\text{output power}}{\displaystyle\text{input power}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{T}_\text{out}\omega_\text{load}}{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{rated}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{T}_\text{out}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle2\pi\text{N}_\text{load}}{\displaystyle60}}{\displaystyle\text{P}_\text{rated}}\tag5$$

Sorry for not mentioning this earlier but Im  talking about an industrial motor being used to mix some material. And i want the mechanical torque the motor is giving me. This formula gives the electrical torque produced at the shaft without considering the windage and friction losses.
